# Where to set default character encoding in VCExpress?

Tags: character-encoding, visual-c++

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP

I want to make it save the files as `utf8` by default,

I've been looking for it in various places,but can't find where the option is

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [suggestion on Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/321798/default-or-unicode-file-save-encoding), you can't set a default.